# improper jbuilder syntax for output during API error handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

The following is a `json.jbuilder`method intended to respond to an API call.

```
if @error_code_98?
  json.set! :chain_category do
    json.set! :error, @error_98_messages
  end
end
```

`@error_code_99 = true` when said errors arise.
`error_98_messages` is a concatenation of string that provide an indentifier with the nature of the error.  They are accumulated as an array of items are handled by the API action.

When the error hits, the instance variable gets populated, but at the end of the action the return message this the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting ':'
  json.set! :chain_category do
```

I thought this was respecting the [syntax for dynamic attribution](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), but that is mistaken.  Where is the syntax off?

Comment: What's "@error_code_98?"? What's the other surrounding code?

Comment: I updated the question for error_code_98.  There is no surrounding code to the condition.

Comment: I don't understand how there can't be any surrounding code, but ok. I asked about `@error_code_98?` because since the syntax of the `json.set!` sequence is correct, therefore the error is almost certainly *before* that code. Is `@error_code_98?` a method? A variable? Is it *actually* `@error_code_98?`, or is it just `@error_code_98` and you've made an assumption regarding the use of `?` in Ruby code?

Comment: Good stab.  I was setting ` @error_code_98 = true`  and I mistakenly assumed the `?` to signify `true`.